# Cannot create AWS EMR with autoscaling via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, autoscaling, aws-cloudformation

I am working on EMR template with autoscaling.
While a static EMR setup with instance group works fine, I cannot attach

`AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget`

As a troubleshooting I've split my template into 2 separate ones. In first I am creating a normal EMR cluster (which is fine). And then in second I have a ScalableTarget definition which fails attach with error:

`11:29:34 UTC+0100  CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget     AutoscalingTarget   EMR instance group doesn't exist: Failed to find Cluster XXXXXXX`

Funny thing is that this cluster DOES exist.
I also had a look at IAM roles but everything seems to be ok there...

Can anyone advice on that matter?
Did anyone for Autoscaling instancegroup to work via Cloudformation?

Answer (score 1):

I have already tried and raised a request with AWS. This autoscaling feature is not yet available using CloudFormation. Now I am using CF for Custom EMR SecGrp creation and S3 etc and in output tab,  I am adding Command line command(aws emr create-cluster...... ). After getting output querying the result to launch Cluster.

Actually, autoscaling can be enabled at the time of cluster launching by using --auto-scaling-role. If we use CF for EMR,  autoscaling feature is not available because it launches cluster without "--auto-scaling-role".

I hope this can be useful...

Comment: do you have a link to your request to AWS?  would be nice to track the status